# rosmake pr2_teleop fails

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As outlined in:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/WorkingWithGazeboOverRos

It fails to make pr2_teleop:

```
cole@z:~$ rosmake pr2_teleop
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pr2_teleop']                              
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/cole/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20111129-103822
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pr2_teleop'] to:
[]                                 
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages ['pr2_teleop']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Any ideas?

I'm using ros-electric in Ubuntu 11.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12126/rosmake-pr2_teleop-fails/) by [c01e](https://answers.ros.org/users/1442/c01e/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I don't think pr2_teleop package comes along with the electric full version.
You have to checkout the package that is under mercurial version control

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/pr2apps/pr2_apps <new_folder_name>
```

And then try compiling it with

```
rosmake pr2_teleop
```

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

**Updated:**
Ya there is this documentation on setting up the ros_workspace and environment in
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)

You can download package in the ros_workspace and ros automatically detects the packages.
Once you setup this and paste your package then you will not get that error.

And you can always update your question here than giving a new answer.

Hope this helps, Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1